# How to convert date into milliseconds in aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

ı am trying convert date to milliseconds

this code is working

```js
db.scheduler.aggregate ( [
{ "$match" :    {       
"payload.measurement.eventTimeMS" : { "$gt" : 1538035287000 }
     } },
]
 ) ;
```

but this not working
Why the following code may not work

query result :Fetched 0 record(s) in 0ms

but there are a lot of data greater than this millisecond

```html
db.scheduler.aggregate ( [
{ "$match" :    {       
"payload.measurement.eventTimeMS" : { "$gt" : {
            $let: {
               vars: {
                   "crYear" : { $year:  new Date() },
                  "crMonth" : { $month:  new Date() }
               },
               in:  {$subtract : [ { $dateFromParts: { 'year' : "$$crYear", 'month' : "$$crMonth", 'day': 1, 'hour' : 00  } }, new Date("1-1-1970")] }
            }
         } }
     } },
 
]
 ) ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`$toLong`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/) to output the milliseconds from epoch in mongodb 4.0 version.

Something like

```
db.scheduler.aggregate(
    {"$match":{"$expr":{"$gt":["$payload.measurement.eventTimeMS",{"$toLong":new Date()}]}}}
);
```

Use `$let`

```
db.scheduler.aggregate({"$match":{
  "$expr":{
    "$gt":[
      "$payload.measurement.eventTimeMS",
      {"$let":{
        "vars":{"date":new Date()},
        "in":{
          "$subtract":[
            {"$dateFromParts":{"year":"$$date","month":"$$date","day":1,"hour":0}},
            new Date(0)
          ]
        }
      }}
    ]
  }
}})
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. but ı use 3.6.4 and also ı must use $let because, ı must find datas in current month

Comment: Yw. Updated answer to include $let.

Comment: this query not working            error: Failed to execute script.

Error:
TypeError: pipeline[(pipeline.length - 1)] is undefined :
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1292:9
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@:1:355
@(shell):1:1

Comment: Can you wrap the query inside [] and try ? Something like `db.scheduler.aggregate([match query]);`